# Angular directive that moves specific view content/functionality to another DOM element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Due to some complex layout issues in my application, I need to be able to "transfer" the content in the element the directive is applied to from the current view/controller to a DOM element outside the view.  What I've currently got is *almost* there.  The only thing not working at this point is the ng-repeat in the content and I'm not sure why.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(_scope, _element, _attrs) {
            var target = $('#'+_attrs.myDirective);
            target.html(_element.html());
            $compile(target.contents())(_scope);
            _element.html('');
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/O9WFxSWqtmo4sGDj7AcE?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because by the time the link function runs the ng-repeat would have converted the element into the comment block which it is going to process to repeated blocks. But that is what you are appending to the target (by getting the innerHTML)and recompiling, which obviously won't work because there is no ng-repeat directive there. try this way, instead using the [`compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) option of the directive capture the element's html before hand and insert that into the target.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        compile: function(elm) {
           /*Get the html*/
           var html = elm.html(); 
           /*Return linking function*/
           return postLink;
         }
      };

    function postLink(_scope, _element, _attrs) { 
        /*Rethink about this, do you just want to restrict users to enter id of the element, no other selectors or even nested level?*/
        var target = $('#'+_attrs.myDirective);
        /*Insert html in to the target*/
        target.html(html); 
        $compile(target.contents())(_scope);
        /*empty is same as .html("") but more explicit*/
        _element.empty(); 
     }
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EzXbdt?p=preview)**

On a different note, instead of appending `#` in your directive you could make your directive more flexible to be able to handle any selector even nested ones. i.e you could take any selector as attribute value.

Ex:-

```
  <div my-directive="#foo"></div>
  <div my-directive=".someparent .child .content"></div>
```